# How to get the URL at HTML? and than How to declare function on the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function shareNaverBlog() {
  var url = "http://blog.naver.com/openapi/share?url=" + getLinkUrl() + "&title=" + document.title;

  window.open(url);
}

function getLinkUrl() {
  var shareUrl = $("#shareButtons").attr("shareLinkUrl");
  //alert($("#shareButtons").attr("shareLinkUrl"));

  if ( location.href != shareUrl ) {
    location.href = shareUrl;
  }

  if ( location.href == shareUrl ) {
    return location.href;
  }

}
```

This code is in the JavaSript about Sharing SNS function and a part of them.

> $("#shareButtons").attr("shareLinkUrl");

==> That var is bring the URL at HTML file.

'shareLinkUrl' is the attribute of div that i defined.

And the value of 'shareLinkUrl' is "http://~test.html".

When i share URL through NaverBlog, however, linked another URL(not that value).

How to get defined URL ? Where is the wrong?

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-kr">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<title>Test_sns_Slave</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//developers.kakao.com/sdk/js/kakao.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://nsk.dl.cdn.cloudn.co.kr/js/share.js"></script>
<script src="//scdn.line-apps.com/n/line_it/thirdparty/loader.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<div>
<table id="Table_01" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td>
      <!-- http://nsk.dl.cdn.cloudn.co.kr 로 시작하는 절대경로로 설정. 500KB 이상일 경우, 카카오톡 공유 시, 이미지 표시 되지 않음  -->
   <img src="http://nsk.dl.cdn.cloudn.co.kr/event/sharing_sns_test/images/am_letter_201605_no_05.jpg" width="100%" >
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div id="shareButtons" align="center" shareLinkUrl="http://nsk.dl.cdn.cloudn.co.kr/event/sharing_sns_test/test.html"></div>

  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need your HTML.
Why don't you just use `src`?

Comment: Because, every time I connect the another html file, length of the code is more longer. I will connect many html files on and on. Finally, I want to link the URL of [Main.html]. Plus, i added HTML.